# prove $\max \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}_i \leq \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{c}_i$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, optimization, special-functions

Can I prove the following (with or without assumptions, e.g. all the elements in $\mathbf{a}$ or $\mathbf{b}$ are positive?

$\max \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}_i \leq \mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{c}_i$

where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ are vectors of dimension $d$.

Let $B = \left[\mathbf{b}_1, \dots, \mathbf{b}_N\right]$, $\max{c}_i$ represents a vector which has the rowwise maximum ofthe matrix B.

e.g.

e.g. $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 \\
5 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 4 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \implies \mathbf{c}_i = \begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
5 \\
4
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Is $\max \mathbf b_i$ the row-wise maximum?

Comment: yes. it is a row-wise max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in $a$ must be non-negative. (Take $a=-1$ for a start of a counterexample)

If $a\ge 0$ then
$$
a^Tb_i = \sum_{j=1}^d a_j b_{i,j} \le \sum_{j=1}^d a_j \max_i b_{i,j}= a^T (\max b_i).
$$
Now take the maximum on the left-hand side.

Comment: What will happen if I assume the other way, i.e. the elements in B are non negative, and the elements in $\mathbf{a}$ can take any values (including negative)?

Comment: I think still the above inequality holds if we assume the elements in B are non negative (and $\mathbf{a}$ are not). Am I correct?

Comment: No: take $d=1$, $a=-1$, $b_1=1$, $b_2=2$. Left-hand side is $-1$, right-hand side is $-2$.

Comment: $\max \mathbf{b}_i$ is not the maximum value in $\mathbf{b}_i$. Instead it contains the row wise maximum values in B. I have changed the notation for $\max \mathbf{b}_i$. Could you kindly reply.

Comment: That is the notation of my answer from the very beginning.